# Reconstructing the image from pieces - puzzle solver

Tags: algorithm, image, computer-vision

Hi
For my programming project I want to write an application which would reconstruct image from pieces. 
Could somebody tell me if there are some known algoritym to reconstrutin images ? I was trying to find some papers about that problem but I find nothing.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of people have looked into this problem. To find relevant resources, the topics you want to look for are image stitching and building panoramas.